# How to time a ListenableFuture

Tags: java, future, latency

I want to track how long an async process takes.
My general approach for synchronous processes is to record the current time, run the process, and finally calculate and record the difference. I use an `AutoCloseable` Timer object to do this. But I'm not sure if this will work for futures.

```
class MyTimer implements AutoCloseable {
  private final long startTime;
  MyTimer(...) {
    startTime = clock.millis();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    recorder.record(clock.millis() - startTime);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work obviously because I'm only recording the time it takes to construct the future, not actually complete it fully

```
public ListenableFuture doSomethingAsync() {
  try(MyTimer timer = new MyTimer()) {
    return thirdPartyLib.readDatabase();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work though

```
public ListenableFuture doSomethingAsync() {
  MyTimer timer = new MyTimer();
  ListenableFuture future = thirdPartyLib.readDatabase();
  future.addListener(() -> timer.close(), listeningExecutorService);
  return future;
}
```

What I'm afraid of is that when the method exits, the method-scoped Timer is garbage collected so when the listener lambda executes, `timer` is in a unpredictable state.
But I'm not sure if the fact that the lambda holds a reference to `timer` prevents it from going away once the method exists.

What's the right way to time the future?

**Edit** Edit to make clear that `readDatabase()` is not my task code but 3rd party library I don't control. Also, `timer` is a custom class I built.

Comment: Why not call `System.nanoTime` at the top and bottom of your task code, and return a `Duration` object as part of the `Future` object’s result?

Comment: @BasilBourque Maybe I misunderstand your suggestion, but what if I don't control the task code?

Comment: Actually, I ran some tests where I force/suggest garbage collection after the method exits, and it seems that the `timer` object doesn't get GC'ed, presumably because the future listener holds a reference to it.
So I think my approach works.
But if someone with more java knowledge can confirm, I'd appreciate it

Comment: `Timer` is a legacy class, as noted in its Javadoc.

Comment: If you don't control the task code, wrap it in your own new task code. Wrap the original task’s result in a new result object, to be returned via the `Future`. Perhaps you can find a way to measure elapsed time outside the task, but that seems awkward.

Comment: If you don't control the task code, you *really* should mention that in the Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque I made some clarifying edits based on your suggestion. But I think my original solution actually works. My listener code copies the `timer` pointer and prevents it from being GC'ed until after it closes, at which point, I capture the duration. I believe this would be similar to what you propose of calling `System.nanoTime` and passing that into the listener, which would copy the primitive `long` into the function.
Let me know if you see any issues

Comment: It is not clear what ListenableFuture is, is it Guice or anything else? If you can control the ExecutorService that executes your tasks, there are mechanisms to instrument the task and measure what you want.

Comment: Nothing is garbage-collected if there's still a reference to it. There's no such thing as "the object is garbage, so I cannot call a method on it" – that's simply not how the GC in Java works.